# Docker compose change the default environment variables file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker-compose.yml I'm trying to change the file which contains the environment variables to .env.local file but nothing works. The values are still thoses from .env file. I'm following this doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option
here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    mysqldb:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: project_mysql
        volumes:
          - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        env_file:
          - .env.local
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
          TZ: "Europe/Berlin"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306/tcp"
```

I also tried to change the name from the file to .env.local.env, .local.env or .variables.env but nothing new happened. I also clear the caches with

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker_clean_ps
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

but the problem is still here. And there is no error message or code

I have no idea about what's going wrong. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL; DR:** You have a problem of **precedence**. Don't redefine variables 
 from `.env.local` with the `environment` key.

---

The [documentation on `env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file) says:

> Environment variables declared in the `environment` section **override** these values – this holds true even if those values are **empty** or **undefined**.

The [priority for **precedence** with the `.env`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file) is

> 1. Compose file
> 2. Shell environment variables
> 3. Environment file
> 4. Dockerfile
> 5. Variable is not defined

```
env_file:
  - .env.local
environment:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE} # Takes precedence over .env.local
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} # Takes precedence over .env.local
  TZ: "Europe/Berlin" # Takes precedence over .env.local
```

---

Note that using the `env_file` key will set **all** the variables from that file, whereas with the `environment` key you have more control on what variable you want to set.

Comment: If I understood correcly, I should define those variables in the compose file ? since those files are versionned isn't it a security issue ?

Comment: No, you can let them in the `.env.local` but you can't redifine them in your compose-file using the `environment` key since it takes **precedence** over the `.env.local` file and file override the values.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer provided by @Michael B. I am providing the adapted compose file of the inquiry:

```
version: '3'

services:
    mysqldb:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: project_mysql
        volumes:
          - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        env_file:
          - ./local.env
        environment:
          TZ: "Europe/Berlin"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306/tcp"
```

Note the removal of the **MYSQL_DATABASE** and **MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD** entries from the environment dictionary due to the fact that based on documentation these would take precedence over the entries defined in the custom env_file.

Comment: I also tried .env.local.env. But I don't have any error

Comment: What I mean is to drop the ```.env``` prefix. Use just ```local.env```, without ```.env``` in front.
Also try using relative path using ```./``` in front: ```./local.env```

Comment: I updated my question. I tried your suggestion but the problem is still here

Comment: I updated my suggestion based on @MickaelB 's answer. As he said you should not define them at all under environment.